# How to run a single unit test method from command line while targeting a specific Gradle build flavor

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I am trying to run just a single Android test case from the command line.

From the IDE I can just right click and run, but from CLI with the following it fails:

```
./gradlew test --tests "com.xyz.b.module.TestClass.testToRun"
```

Error:

```
> Unknown command-line option '--tests'.
```

How can I run a single UNIT TEST method? I want to emphasis that I want to run a single unit test, not an instrumentation test from command line.

**Update**: I have a camera app.  Imagine that I have a build variant called `usCameraDebug`.  (That means united states camera debug) Now can you tell me how to run a single test case i called `mySingleTest`?

I tried this as you mentioned: `./gradlew test --tests "*mySingleTest"`

and `./gradlew app:usCameraDebug test --tests "*mySingleTest"`

and  also: `./gradlew app:usCameraDebugUnitTest --tests "*mySingleTest"`
 but it . does not work. caan you tell me exactly what to type based on my build variant. its in a module called "app"  as defaulted.

Here is the test I want to run:

```
package  com.xyz.cameras.parts
    @Test
        fun mySingleTest(){
            assertEquals(12,13)
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a wildcard in the pattern while looking for the test name, and make sure to use module + flavor. `--tests` will not work with `./gradlew test` or `./gradlew check`

Try this pattern -> `./gradlew :<module>:<flavor> --tests "*textThatTestNameContains*"`

Example ->
`./gradlew :profile:testDebug --tests "*my_profile*"` will run this test:

```
@Test
public void my_profile_pageview()
```

Additionally, running with `--info` flag helps to see the tests themselves or `--debug` for more output. e.g.
`./gradlew --info :profile:testDebug --tests "*my_profile*"`

Comment: i put a updated . section in my question, can you check. the things you mentioned are not working

Comment: @j2emanue Hey! Check my updated answer. I believe this should work for you. I think you may just need an extra `*` at the end of your test name. Try `./gradlew app:usCameraDebugUnitTest --tests "*mySingleTest*"` I don't think you need a colon before app, but it wouldn't hurt to add it. `./gradlew :app:usCameraDebugUnitTest --tests "*mySingleTest*"`

Comment: this one works for me: /gradlew :app:usCameraDebugUnitTest --tests "*mySingleTest", thanks